# How to create a Document Library Item without a file in sharepoint 2010?

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, sharepoint-designer, document-library, designer-workflow, design

wish you save my life. I am now doing a sharepoint project but I have little experience.

My requirement:

1. Design a contract creation/approval process for a company
2. There are many kinds of contracts, can be grouped as Standard and non-standard. each contract has different workflow.
3. The Standard contract is word document auto generated by some parameters (counter party name, effective date etc)
4. The non-standard contract is word document uploaded by users, but users still need to set some parameters (counter party name etc), because we need these info in workflow
5. After the users set parameters for standard contract (or set parameters and upload document for non-standard contract), the contract will trigger the corresponding workflow.
6. When the workflow is approved, the final documents will appear in a library document.(for standard contract, the document is auto-generated, for non-standard, the document is uploaded by users)

My investigation:

1. I can create word document by parameters with these steps:  A. Create a document library with additional properties (like Counterparty name). B.  Create a template for this library named template.docx. C.  In word, Insert->Quick Parts->Document Property as placeholder for meta data. D.  In Sharepoint designer-> Workflow Editor, add 'Create List Item' for this library, pass corresponding parameters, we are done auto generating word document.
   [Refer to here](http://blogs.technet.com/b/brenclarke/archive/2009/04/15/automatically-create-word-documents-which-include-list-fields.aspx)
2. I want to create a library 'Contracts' with many content types(like Standard A, Standard B, non-standard A, non-standard B), each content type will bind to corresponding workflow, for standard types, they also define a specific word template.
3. When users create Standard contract, they are asked to input some parameters, after they submit, the workflow will run and generate a doc in this library.
4. When users create non-standard contract, they are asked to input some parameters and upload the contract, after they submit, the workflow will run.

My problem:
 I was stuck in step 3 above.

1. How do users create a standard contract without uploading a file in a document library? (the file is generated after workflow)
2. Or do you have better design solutions? (It might be possible by using a separate library for final documents, but that is my last option)

Much appreciate to your ideas

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use a list to capture the initial parameters and trigger the workflow which creates your document in a separate library.  You could then either delete the original list item or update it with a link to the new item in the library.

Comment: Thanks Dave, I thought about using list. The only problem is that users want the same library to create and view all contracts (whether processing or finished). I will research more for this, thanks!

Comment: In that case you could use the list as the main point for them to enter/search/edit etc and create the files in a separate library with a link column from the list.